# How can I get hard bounced emails from Amazon Pinpoint?

Tags: email, aws-pinpoint

I have launched a campaign with Amazon Pinpoint and didn't enable event stream. Now there is 4.6% of hard bounced emails which is not a good number.
I am trying to get those emails and remove from the list, but can not find them.

What I have tried so far is querying metrics for the campaign, but only got the number of hard bounced emails, tried to get the suppression list, but didn't find how.
Also account suppression list is not activated so I can not query them from there.

Does anyone had a problem like this? Can you please help me detect those emails?
Thank you.